# Changing Graphic Card

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

my laptop has a 2 graphic card and the Intel gaphic card selected default.

**lspci |  egrep 'VGA|3D|Display'**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev 83)
```

I want to use AMD Graphic card, how i can switch this?

Comment: How are you checking which card is selected by default?

Comment: System Settings -> Details